# How to revert commits without loosing changes?

Tags: git

I just realized that the last three commits i have made have been against the master branch.

[image]

I know I could do a

```
Git reset --hard
```

I tried a

```
Git reset --soft
```

but it doesn't seam to have done anything.

I need to get these changes uncommitted so that i can move them to their own branch.  I am desperate not to loose all of these changes.  I cant push to master without a code review so i need to get these changes out of the master branch and into their own.

Comment: Why don't you just `cherry-pick` them over to the new branch?

Comment: Ok cherry-pick i have not heard of that before.  Let me go look it up.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Yes, cherry-picking them is a way to get them on the right branch, but it won't get master rid of them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `git reset --soft` was the right way, but you also have to point to the right commit, and after the reset you're not completely done yet.

```
# reset to the commit BEFORE (^) the first bad one
git reset --soft 274c94^
```

At this point, the modifications described in the three "bad" commits we've just undone are in your working tree, waiting to be added and committed

```
# then switch branch to whichever branch suits your needs
git checkout myBranch

# Add and commit the way you usually do, for example :
git add .
git commit -m "Awesome message"
```

Comment: Cowoker said just pointed out this "You create new branch. Push it to be sure. Reset master to origin"   your solution worked thank you :)